# System.Text.Json не сериализует классы наследники в списке

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core

Есть следующая структура классов:

```
    public class foo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class derived : foo
    {
        public string lastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class container
    {
        public List<foo> foos { get; set; }
    }
```

Мне надо составить список и отправить его на сервер предварительно засереализировав его.

```
var c = new container
{
    foos = new List<foo>
    {
        new derived{name = "first", lastName = "first"},
        new derived{name = "second", lastName = "second"},
        new derived{name = "third", lastName = "third"}
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(c));
```

Для сериализации использую System.Text.Json, стандартную либу в нет коре.
Получаю след вывод

```
{"foos":[{"name":"first"},{"name":"second"},{"name":"third"}]}
```

Почему нет полей которые дополнил класс наследника?

Например в Newtonsoft все поля сериализируются.

Проблему можно частично решить если сделать список обьектов

```
public List<object> foos { get; set; }
```

В таком случае все поля сериализируются. Но такой вариант немного корявый и мне не подходит.

Comment: [Пишут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#polymorphic-serialization) что без своего JsonConverter ни как

Comment: Удалось найти решение?

Comment: Сделали класс Container шаблонным, как в совете ниже. Майкрософт запилили галимый сериализатор.

Comment: Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его поставив зеленую галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: Отмечу, что классы-обёртки наподобие `container` являются бессмысленными, засоряют код, усложняют работу с ним и затрудняют понимание. Нужен список (коллекция) - создайте список! Обёртка не нужна.

Comment: Я упростил объект, в реальном объекте у нас по мимо списка есть куча других свойств

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще да, странный получится json, если массив будет содержать разные типы данных. Как это десереализовать потом? Без костылей никак. Придется иметь кастомные контвертеры либо специальную модель данных для сериализации.

Я бы лучше организовал контейнер так:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Foo
{
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

public class Container<T> where T : Foo
{
    public List<T> foos { get;  set; }
}
```

Тогда код, который вы привели, будет выглядеть так:

```cs
var c = new Container<Derived>
{
    foos = new List<Derived>
    {
        new Derived{name = "first", lastName = "first"},
        new Derived{name = "second", lastName = "second"},
        new Derived{name = "third", lastName = "third"}
    }
};

Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(c));
```

И работать так как нужно

```json
{"foos":[{"lastName":"first","name":"first"},{"lastName":"second","name":"second"},{"lastName":"third","name":"third"}]}
```